# Mysql windows 7 database access

Tags: mysql, windows, ms-access

we are currently working on a local webpage. We have an appache server plus a mysql server, and we want to incorporate a .mdb file which is runned on microsoft access. We are currently running it on a Windows 7 computer that runs those service. We are using joomla to create the site.

Is there anyway to make the database working on the webpage?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Is there a need for two completely different DB sources? Is it possible to import the data in Access file to MySQL? Also the question is rather open and broad? Is there specific issue you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is inherently flawed.  I'd import whatever data was in Access into MySQL and let the web page access it from there.

If that's not possible, you'll need a JDBC driver to connect to Access.  I don't believe the ODBC bridge driver ships with 64-bit Java, so if your Windows 7 server is 64 bit you're out of luck.  I'm not aware of any free JDBC drivers for Access.

Once you have a suitable JDBC driver you can connect to Access just as you would MySQL.

I still wouldn't advise that you do so.  I believe Access was intended for single user access only, not for shared access by multiple requests.  Let MySQL do the work here, especially since you're already using it.  No need for two relational databases.

Comment: RE: "I believe Access was intended for single user access only" -- While it is true that ACE/Jet is generally not the best choice of database back-end for a web application, ACE/Jet has always been able to handle multiple concurrent users.